# How to disable all searching from the location bar in firefox?

Tags: firefox, search

(I found similar older questions, but their answers are now obsolete.)

How can I completely disable searching from Firefox's location bar?  In other words, if I type some search terms in the location bar, as opposed to a valid, reachable server address, I want Firefox to respond with a "Server Not Found" error.

I tried doing this through Settings, but, no matter what I do, Firefox keeps accepting search terms in the location bar, and passing them off to my chosen (and only) search engine.  (Of course, I tried to delete this last search engine, but Firefox won't let me.)

Alternatively, is there a simple way I can implement a "do-nothing" search engine that I can then choose as my default search engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1
type the "about:config" on Firefox location bar and Press Enter
[image]

Step 2
Find the keyword.enabled and make it as "false"
[image]

Step 3
Go to Firefox Setting then click on Privacy and Security
Find Address Bar
When using the address bar, Disable suggest
Browsing history
Bookmarks
Open tabs
Shortcuts
Search engines

Source -[How to Fix Firefox Address Bar Search Not Working](https://youtu.be/MDCBHcA0SJY)

Comment: That worked like gangbusters, thank you!  Also, nice video!  One suggestion for such videos: please mention somewhere (preferably in the video's title) the version of Firefox you used.  In my experience, such Firefox recipes have a distressingly short shelf-life; e.g., a 2-3 years shelf-life is not at all unusual.  Hence, if the recipe does become obsolete, making the version you used readily visible will help future viewers with their troubleshooting.